# Can I use expression in square bracket to access property of class by "this" keyword?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  userSubmitted = false;
  accountSubmitted = false;

  userForm!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onSubmit(type: string): void {
    this[type + 'Submitted'] = true;
    if(this[type + 'Form'].invalid)
      return;
    console.log(this[type + 'Form'].value);
  }
```

I want to avoid having to write onSubmitUser() and onSubmitAccount() function

Comment: So if you don't want to write the function where are you going to put the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not! `this` is an object just like any other object defined inside curly braces `{}` so there is no reason you cannot do that.